# Setting CSS for consistent textarea positioning on Retina Displays

Tags: html, css, textarea, retina-display

My problem is two-fold. First, the text areas on [this page](http://rjmathewson.github.io) are overlapping [when displayed on a Retina Display](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7o5d3a5gg0k9he9/Screen%20Shot%202016-05-10%20at%205.46.59%20PM.png?dl=0). How do I modify the HTML/CSS to get consistent spacing on Retina lower res displays?

Second, I don't have a Retina display myself. I have been unable to repro the problem by customizing the pixel ratio on Chrome or FF. Are there other options that might allow me to repro the result in the screenshot?

html and CSS for the "Customer" text areas and the CSS for adjoining container are as follows:

```css
.id_fields {
  width: 150px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
.cp_company {
      position:absolute;
      width:130px;
      height:30px;
      margin-right: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 40px;
      overflow: auto;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: small;
      color: #000000;
    }
  .container {
        width:160px;
        height:150px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-right: inherit;
        padding-left:auto;
        Padding-right:auto;
        display:inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="id_fields" style="display:inline-block;">
  <a for="title" style="width: 130px; font-size: small; justify-content: center; display: flex; margin-bottom: 29px; margin-top: 89px;">Customer </a>
  <textarea class="cp_company" style="margin-top: -116px; margin-bottom: 0px;" name="cust_fullfillment_company" placeholder="Company"></textarea>
  <textarea class="cp_company" style="margin-top: -76px;" name="cust_fullfillment_name" placeholder="Name"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: You usually can simulate a high-density display by simply zooming out with your browser. However, in this case that won't reproduce the problem. What browser are they using on the retina display? By the way, I can get the fields to overlap by resizing the input boxes. Are you sure the people who sent you the screen shot weren't doing that?

Comment: They are seeing the overlap on both Safari and Chrome. I can't say for sure that they were not resizing the input boxes, but I don't believe they were.

Answer (score 0):

No silver bullet here, but reducing the width of the overlapping fields had the biggest impact. From there it was combination of CSS tweaks including replacing the textarea label with plain text and margin adjustments.

```css
.id_fields{
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100px;
      margin-left: 2px;
      margin-right: 2px;
      margin-top: -45px;
    }
    .cp_company {
      position:absolute;
      width:80px;
      height:30px;
      margin-right: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 40px;
      overflow: auto;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: small;
      color: #000000;
    }
.cust_name {
    display:inline-block;
    width:130px;
    height:30px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    overflow: auto;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: #000000;
  }
    .cp_label {
      text-align:center;
      font-size:small;
      padding-left:13px;
      padding-right: 18px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="id_fields" style="margin-left:30px;">
                    <textarea class="cp_company" style="margin-top: -72px; margin-bottom: 0px;"name="cust_fullfillment_company" placeholder="Company"></textarea>
                    <textarea class="cp_company" style="margin-top: -34px;"name="cust_fullfillment_name" placeholder="Name"></textarea>
                    <a class="cp_label">Customer</a>
                  </div>
```